# Tree traversal with fixed size stack in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

Is it possible to traverse a tree structure (specifically an octree, the 3-D version of a binary tree) by using a  fixed sized stack? I do not want to use recursion, since my octree is
quite deep.

I am traversing the tree to do a range search problem, to find all the points closest to a queried point. So in my traversal, I do not walk down those subtrees rooted at nodes which my search region does not intersect.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Traverse tree without recursion and stack in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3214312/traverse-tree-without-recursion-and-stack-in-c)

Comment: I guessed that you want to avoid the recursion because of practical limitation on the machine's call stack size.

Answer (score 3):

If your octree has parent pointers, I think you can traverse it without a stack at all (see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3214312/traverse-tree-without-recursion-and-stack-in-c), for example). Without that, you will need a stack that is as deep as the depth of your tree, regardless of how many branches are skipped.

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can traverse a tree without using a deep native call stack, using continuation passing style techniques, or (and this is grossly the same) by making a virtual machine, with its call stack implemented as a heap data, or (yet another point of view) by coding a stack automata with the stack implemented as an explicit heap data structure (e.g. a `std::stack`).

Think of it otherwise, your C++ naive code could run on a Turing machine, and these beasts don't have any stack.

As [Ted Hopp's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8779544/841108) suggests, you might be inspired by [Deutsch-Schorr-Waite](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs312/2007fa/lectures/lec21-schorr-waite.pdf)'s Garbage Collection techniques (with a few additional bits per node to temporarily flip the reference direction and remember that) to have a "stack-less" traversal (but you need additional bits in each node). But I believe that having your own stack inside a `std::stack` or `std::vector` is probably simpler.

Comment: _"A rose by any other name..."_ Continuation passing style uses the stack. Using the heap to implement a stack is still a stack. Simulating a stack on a Turing machine is still using a stack. Also, OP seems to be asking about any stack, not the call stack specifically. The concern seems to be extra memory usage, not avoiding a structure explicitly called "stack".

Comment: I agree, I never thought otherwise. I just spoke of avoiding a *deep **native call** stack*; and my understanding of "avoid deep recursion" is only about the machine stack.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, you can traverse the octree with a fixed-size stack.

The fixed-size just needs to be as big as the longest possible octree depth.

Bear in mind that with an octree, **each depth traversal can be recorded with only 3 bits of memory**.  For each of the three dimensions, you only need to record whether you went in a positive or negative direction.

So even if your octree goes 1000-deep, you can store the recursion with 375 bytes.

Comment: That's not a fixed-size stack. For any fixed N, there will be octrees so deep that recursion cannot be stored in N bytes. (10^-1000)*log(N) is still O(log N).

Comment: @TedHopp: Your math is correct, but "there will be octrees so deep" is a theoretical postulate, no?  This seems to be a real-world problem.